# Private declaration seems invalid

Tags: php

```
class global_class extends Timemine
{

  private $DBPrefix = '';

  public function __construct()
  {
    global $DBPrefix;

    // Load settings
    self::loadsettings();

    $this->database = $db;
    $this->DBPrefix = $DBPrefix;
    .
    .
```

`$DBPrefix` is declared outside as a private but inside the function its redeclared? as global.
Is this correct?
Thank you.

Comment: Your answer is a few lines down.  `$this->DBPrefix = $DBPrefix;`  It is not "redeclared."  Members in php are never accessible without `$this`

Answer (score 1):

`$DBPrefix` is actually not redeclared. There are two versions of the variable. The first one (`private $DBPrefix = '';`) is a member variable, the second one (`global $DBPrefix`) is a local scope variable of the constructor (which refers to a third global version of the variable, but let's leave this aside). See the PHP docs about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) for more information

The value of the member variable is then set to the same value as the local scope variable with this line: `$this->DBPrefix = $DBPrefix;` So after this line both versions have the same value. Technically, your code is correct.

However, using `global`is usually bad. It is probably better to pass `$DBPrefix` in the constructor like:

```
public function __construct($DBPrefix) {

    // Load settings
    self::loadsettings();

    $this->database = $db;
    $this->DBPrefix = $DBPrefix;
}
```